# How to do row grouping in datatables with a separator for each group?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to group rows of a datatable and separate each group with a separator like in this image but I can't figure out how to do it.

[image: Check this image for what i mean to achieve]

I would really appreciate if someone tells me how to do this.

Comment: See [row grouping](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html), does that work for you?

Comment: To some extent row grouping could work but the problem is row grouping can be applied using only one column but as you can see in the image i have to apply grouping using more than one column. What should i do in that case?

Comment: We are looking for exactly the same. Has anyone found a solution in the meantime?